# request.forms.get not working with bottle.py app

Tags: python, request, bottle

I am using the bottle.py app to connect two pages, an HTML form page and a result page that takes the form responses, which are names, and converts them to a corresponding value that I have paired in a dictionary.

This is the HTML code I am trying to link up:

```
<select id = "sample">
               <option value = "Basketball">Basketball</option>
               <option value = "Golf">Golf</option>
               <option value = "Football">Football</option>
```

And then this is where it takes the choice and converts it to the corresponding value

```
from bottle import request

top = request.forms.get('sample')
val = d[top]
answer = float[val]
```

And then this is my bottle app code

```
from bottle import default_app, route, post, template

@route('/')
def form():
    return template('form.html')

@post('/convert')
def convert():
    return template('result.html')

application = default_app()
```

However, when I run this, it says KeyError:None. So at first I thought it was a problem with my dictionary, but when I ran the dictionary by itself, it printed like it should. So then I commented out every section except for the request.forms.get line to see if it was pulling the name, and tried to print the variable, and it said that the variable was undefined, so that's where the problem lies. Does anyone see what the problem in this is?

Answer (score 0):

Despite being a global object, `request` is initialized only during request-response cycle, so it must be accessed only within a route function, not from module's global scope.